# Logging into unity failed

Tags: unity-game-engine, authentication

Specs:

- Latest version of unity editor
- Personal license
- OS: Linux, Debian 10

Hi,
my problem is that I cannot sign into the asset store or sign in at all from within unity.
I have already installed unity hub and the latest release for the editor.

If I click on "account" in the top right corner of the unity editor, I can choose to sign in, and upgrade to pro.
After clicking log in I get an error saying: "You must install the unity hub to sign in and use unity services."
Same error while trying to log into the asset store.
The thing is I have already installed unity hub and signed in -- I installed unity *from* the unity hub!

Whats going on here?
(I can download the unity hub, and it is auto logged in for me, and I can sign in on the website as well...)

Comment: With `Latest` you refer to the latest **stable** release (2019.4) or maybe an alpha/beta version?

Comment: @derHugo I have `2019.4.0f1 LTS`

Comment: Close Unity. End all processes related to Unity. Restart.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it.
If anyone wants to know how I fixed it:

- Enter the asset store from the unity editor
- You should see *sign in* and *create account*.
- Click *create account* (Names may have been slightly different).
- You should see a screen prompting you to sign up, don't fill it out. Press the *Already have an account* and that should log you in.

Hope it helps!

Comment: wow it worked! Thanks acoder! Yes clicking Signin first directs it to Unity Hub which fails to communicate with the Unity Editor even if you signin successfully....A strange bug which Unity doesnt want to address as it doesnt support all Linux distros. So the idea is to signin within the Asset Store tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and finally I realized that my Vpn software doen't support Apps (it actually tunnled websites in browser). I downloaded a new vpn software and now I can log in to unity from Hub and I can use asset's store in Unity editor.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem!!! The problem is that when you click to "sign in"... Unity tries to open a browser, but he dont know which one to open edge? google?.

1. Go to your favorite browser like "edge" or "chrome"
2. got to settings and let the browser know that its your standart browser
   3 try to sign in at your installed unity hub
   sry for bad english.